How to add VoiceOver accessibility to CarouselView in swiftUI
In swift we can achieve as mentioned in How to have accessible swipe action for iCarousel:
extension iCarousel {
    override open func accessibilityScroll(_ direction: UIAccessibilityScrollDirection) -> Bool {
        super.accessibilityScroll(direction)

        if direction == UIAccessibilityScrollDirection.left {
            self.scroll(byOffset: 1, duration: 1.0)
        }
        if direction == UIAccessibilityScrollDirection.right {
            self.scroll(byOffset: -1, duration: 1.0)
        }
        return true
    }
}

and post a desire (e.g. page number) in iCarousel delegate method carouselDidEndScrollingAnimation, you may also change the accessibilityLabel and other accessibility related values here.
func carouselDidEndScrollingAnimation(_ carousel: iCarousel) {
    self.carousel.accessibilityLabel = accLabels[currentItemIndex]
    self.carousel.accessibilityValue = accValues[currentItemIndex]
    UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityAnnouncementNotification,
                                    "item \(currentItemIndex + 1) of \(self.items.count)")
}

Also in viewDidLoad set the initial accessibilityLabel as well as:
self.carousel.accessibilityTraits = UIAccessibilityTraitUpdatesFrequently

How can we achieve this in swiftUI?

Your question is unclear. Do you want to know how to wrap iCarousel for SwiftUI or how to add the accessibility behavior to an existing SwiftUI view?

how to add the accessibility behavior to an existing SwiftUI view?
